# когда запускаю виртуально устройство - белый экран (genymotion)

Tags: android, экран, genymotion, arm, эмулятор

Может это связано как то с тем что у меня не интел?
[image: Вот так запускается и дальше ничего]

[процессор](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh1P0.jpg)

[image: адаптер в компьютере]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Обновить интел до талого.
2. Включить режим максимальной производительности т.к. если минималка то цвета до 16бит используются
3. Убедиться что используется цвета 32 бита и перезапустить.

Comment: у меня процессор не интел

Comment: как убедиться что используется цвета 32 бита? как это сделать

Comment: vga - intel, правой кнопкой мыши по значку батареи и нажать высокая производительность и будет 32 бита. И еще вопрос зачем на 2 гб оперативы - 64 разрядная архитектура?)

Comment: а нет значка батареи, это стационарный а не ноутбук